# Problems with deleting objects in Grails - slow, and still not really deleted

Tags: grails

This is probably a rookie mistake, so forgive me in advance. I have searched high and low for a solution, but without result - so I thourght I'd add my first post here :-)

I have two domain classes, one called Domain and one called Page. As below code shows, the Domain has many Page(s).

```
class Domain {
          ...
    static hasMany = [  pages : Page, ... ]
    static mapping = {
        pages lazy:true
    }
}

class Page {
    String identifier
    ...
    static belongsTo = [ domain : Domain ]
    static hasMany = [ ... ]
    static constraints = {
        identifier(blank:false, unique:'domain')
    }
    static mapping = {
        ...
        domain lazy:true
    }
}
```

My application has a long algorithm that amongst other things creates Pages on a Domain. If you run the algorithm with the same arguments as a previous run, it will start by deleting all pages created by the previous run before running the algorithm again.

I have two problems:

Problem #1
When I delete a specific Page from a Domain using:

```
def domain = page.domain
domain.removeFromPages(page);
page.delete()
domain.save(flush:true)
```

This causes Hibernate to fetch and load all pages of the domain, which ultimately fires several thousands queries (the domain has MANY pages). How am I improving perfomance on this? - Executing sql directly to delete the page make the database and hibernate get out of sync.

Problem #2
When I later create the page again:

```
def page = new Page(identifier:'...').save(failOnError:true)
```

I get the:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

Any help is welcome - I am losing my mind here :-/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to think about a small redesign of your classes.
First, remove the pages-collection from "Domain"

```
Class Domain {
  // no pages here
}
```

And then put a simple reference to "Domain" in "Page"

```
Class Page {    
    String identifier
    Domain domain
    ...
}
```

This makes the handling of your pages much easier.
I don't know if this is really an option for you because you have to make changes to your existing code, but it can save you a lot of trouble with your large collections. There is also a [presentation by Burt Beckwith](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/files/169/gorm%20grails%20meetup%20presentation.pdf) about this.

Comment: Hi,Yes I have seen that trick before. So I implemented it just that relationship. And that certainly boosted my performance issue when deleting a page. I still however have problem #2. I am deleting the page with page.delete(flush:true) and if I try to query the page in the next line I get zero hits. But probably ten lines later, I decide to create the page again and get the "org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session" :-(

Answer (score 0):

For a batch delete, see this post by the [IntelliGrape](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/09/29/gorm-batch-deletes-made-easy-with-load-method/)

I had to fetch and store holidays stored in a remote system, and on each fetch delete the ones I had stored locally and this came up like this:

```
Holiday.list()*.delete(flush:true)
```

The * is where all the magic happen. Note that you can restrict the number of items to delete with the list() method.

On a batch, note that you can also use the following to perform a batch.

```
def session = sessionFactory.openSession()
def tx = session.beginTransaction()

... 
for(holiday in holidays) {
        def h = new Holiday(..)
        session.save(h) 
}
sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()
tx.commit()
```

Comment: Hi, Thx a lot for the response. But the performance part wasn't as much an issue of batch deletion but more of a relationship problem - as the other answer pointed out. But the war isn't over yet. Even though I am deleting the page with page.delete(flush:true) and in lines after cannot fetch the deleted page - it magically still exists. Because when I later want to create the Page again, I get the "org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session"